# Which movement command should I use for transporting multiple matrices and images in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matrix, matplotlib

I wrote a script that retrieves data from a thermal camera I'm using and converts it into two forms. One is a matrix inside of a .txt, and the other is a standard png. When I run it, I instantly get hundreds of files, some png's, some .txt's and the like. What I would like to do is have it so that as soon as I start my script, it creates a folder called "UVC-Run-%s" % (now.[whatever time it is])" and inside there would be two folders called say, Pyplot and Numpy. I would like that all of my png's go to the pyplot one, and all of the .txt's to the numpy one. I tried using os.rename, but something isn't working. How do I move/create my files inside of those two folders inside the main one?

```
os.makdirs("UVC-Run-%s" % (now.[whatever time it is]))
os.mkdirs("those 2 folders inside UVC-Run...")
try:
        while True:
          data = q.get(True, 500)
          if data is None:
            break
          now = datetime.datetime.now()
          data = cv2.resize(data[:,:], (80, 60))
          print "%s" % (now.microsecond)
          np.savetxt("uvc-capture-file-%s" % (now.microsecond),np.array(data))
#save this (^) to Numpy
          mpl.imsave(arr=data,fname="test-%s" % (now.microsecond)) #and save it to png's
      finally:
        libuvc.uvc_stop_streaming(devh)
      print "done"
    finally:
      libuvc.uvc_unref_device(dev)
  finally:
    libuvc.uvc_exit(ctx)
```

Comment: I cannot sort that indentation out for you. Please fix it so that it's an _accurate_ representation of what you're looking at. You also haven't closed some quotes somewhere (1st line?). That all I see when I opened this question, not the text itself.

Comment: At the top, you could say `txtdir = 'txtdir'` and `imdir = 'imdir'` (use any names you want). Then execute `os.mkdir(txtdir)` and `os.mkdir(imdir)`. Then in the `savetext` call, change the filename to this: `os.path.join(txtdir, "uvc-capture-file-%s" % (now.microsecond))`, and similarly for `imsave`.